# From Json Get vlaue of key Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to do an api call to get a list of subcategories.
my json looks like this

```
    {
        "description": "Flower", 
        "name": "Flower", 
        "parent_id": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "description": "Moon", 
        "name": "Moon", 
        "parent_id": "1"
    }
]
```

This is what i have attepted so far.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('button').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/subcategories?sstr=ball",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('.results').append('<ul class="list"></ul>');
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            console.log(data)
            $('.list').append('<li>' + key + ': ' + value + '</li>');
        });
    })
    .fail(function(event) {
        alert(event.status);
    });
});
    </script>
```

The result i get is
0: [object Object]
1: [object Object]
2: [object Object]
 what i would like is the list of names.

Comment: `.parseJSON(your json)`

Comment: `$('.list').append('<li>' + key + ': ' + value.description + ',' + value.name+ ','  + value.parent_id  + '</li>');`

Comment: @ImmortalDude :  it's already an object..... `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: oh ok then just use `value.name`, the `key` part is for indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where `value` is the array element which is an object instead get its name property.

```
$('.list').append('<li>' + key + ': ' + value.name + '</li>');
```

---

Since it's an array you can use JavaScript [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method also.

```
data.forEach(function(value, key) {
  $('.list').append('<li>' + key + ': ' + value.name + '</li>');
});
```

---

Or you can reduce it to a single append statement by generating the HTML string using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods.

```
 $('.results').append(
   '<ul class="list">' +
   data.map(function(value, key) {
     return '<li>' + key + ': ' + value.name + '</li>');
   }).join('') + 
  '</ul>'
 );
```

Comment: Thank you Very much

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse your json string to convert it in a javascript array.

So do this -> var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Now,

```
var html = "";

html += '<ul>';

$.each( json_data, function( key, value ) { 

  html += '<li>'+key+':'+value['name']+'</li>';       

});

html += '</ul>';

$('.list').html(html);
```

I think that will do the trick.